# I'm trying to find a better way to find nth most rare element in array

Tags: c#, performance, linq, memory

Say,

```
elements=5, 4, 2, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5  
return elements.GroupBy(x=>x).OrderBy(x=>x.Count()).Skip(n-1).FirstOrDefault().Key;
```

For a larger array, the memory limit is exceeded. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you please share some figures about the array size and the memory footprint?

Comment: Compile 64-bit.

Comment: Internally `.GroupBy()` creates a lot of working arrays and also uses `QuickSort()` which is recursive. Is the issue a stackoverflow due to too many recursive calls, or is it an out-of-memory exception due to the many array allocations and the 2Gb process limit?

Comment: Are the elements always going to be number between one and five (or in a similarly tight range)? If so there are shortcuts you can use to compute the count very quickly.

Comment: This assumes that there are no groupings with the same number of elements (equally rare).  With `int[] elements = { 1, 2, /* 2, */ 3, 3, 3 };` and `int n = 2` this returns `2`, not `3`.

Answer (score 1):

*Larger* is a relative term, but you could try going back to basics and count yourself.

```
var elements = new[] { 5, 4, 2, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5 };
var counts = new Dictionary<int, int>(capacity: elements.Length); // Worst case capacity
for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
{
    counts.TryGetValue(elements[i], out var count);
    counts[elements[i]] = ++count;
}

var n = 5;
var nthRarest = counts.OrderBy(x => x.Value).Skip(n - 1).FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine($"'{nthRarest.Key}' with {nthRarest.Value}"); //'5' with 5
```

---

### Re: @mjwills' TryGetValue comment.

My original counter used `ContainsKey` and @mjwills suggested `TryGetValue`.  Here are some low quality benchmarks:

- with ContainsKey: '3' with 99829 @ 00:00:00.0808146
- with TryGetValue: '3' with 99829 @ 00:00:00.0594995

```
var elements = Enumerable.Range(0, 1_000_000).Select(i => r.Next(0,10)).ToArray();
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

(...)

var elapsed = sw.Elapsed;
Console.WriteLine($"'{nthRarest.Key}' with {nthRarest.Value} @ {elapsed}");
```

Old way:

```
if (!counts.ContainsKey(elements[i]))
    counts[elements[i]] = 1;
else
    counts[elements[i]] += 1;
```

Comment: `TryGetValue` may give you a speed boost.

Comment: Oh, as in: `counts.TryGetValue(elements, out var count); count++; counts[number] = count;`...

Comment: Depending on the distribution of values, a regular array *might* be better than a dictionary. Also, the code only seem to build the histogram, not the sorting or selection of n'th least frequent item.

Comment: I suggest initializing the dictionary with a capacity equal to the number of elements to avoid future allocations.

Comment: I've added capacity (with a comment) and also made it return the rarest element (was with most occurrences) as I realised that the question was about the rarest element.

Comment: `.Skip(n-1).FirstOrDefault()` N-th rarest.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thanks for pointing this out. Updated.